# zoo_add_auth() return ZOK even if invalid credentials provided

Tags: c, apache-zookeeper

zoo_add_auth() return ZOK even if wrong credentials provided. But when wrong credentials provided, the program cannot get data on the zookeeper node. It seems that the zookeeper server does not **check** my credentials. Only zookeeper node you try to access will **check** the credentials I provided. 
Am I right?